# Reload properties file automatically after change in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am having a `servlet` where I am updating the properties file value from the form values but the changes are reflecting only when I restart my server. Please provide me a solution for this.

**Servlet:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String database = request.getParameter("appDB");
     Properties prop = new Properties();
     String PROPERTY_FILENAME = "F:/Dashboard/Dashboard1.0/src/server_url.properties";
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(PROPERTY_FILENAME);
    // load a properties file
    prop.load(file);

    OutputStream output = null;

    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream(PROPERTY_FILENAME);
        // set the properties value
        prop.setProperty("DemoApps_DataBase", database);
                    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("DemoApps_DataBase"));

        // save properties to project root folder
        prop.store(output, null);

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a File object pointing to the properties file and keep the lastModifiedTime, everytime compare the lastModifiedWith the previous stored time if there is a change re-read the file.

Comment: this should help http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077490/learn-java/java-tip-125--set-your-timer-for-dynamic-properties.html